# Using Google Analytics - I want to determine which links in my navigation are useful

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking at the corporate site I manage, which has over 50 links in the navigation.  I want to use analytics to determine if some of those links can be removed, and visitors can find those pages through various other ways (search, sibling sidebar navigation, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the links are standard links that exist at the time your GA code is executed, you can look at the `visitor flow` report.  If the page gets a lot of traffic to it vs other pages, you should see it in the report off the bat.  But if not, you may need to make a segment to filter for it first.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Google Analytics doesn't separate two different links pointing to the same URL. That's why I use [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/) heat maps in situations like yours.

To track internal links accurately with Google Analytics, you have to turn on the [enhanced link attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en). This requires a change to the tracking code and marking each html link element with an unique id.